# Flutter flutter_zoom_drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am watching a tutorial on youtube (https://youtu.be/Evu19gTKaFo) to build a menu for my mobile application. I followed the steps but I had a problem when I ran the application:
-how it's supposed to look: [goodLook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXujY.png)
-how it's actually looking:
[badLook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23SDL.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_zoom_drawer/config.dart';

import 'package:flutter_zoom_drawer/flutter_zoom_drawer.dart';

import 'main_screen.dart';
import 'menu_page.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Dashboard> createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ZoomDrawer(
      style: DrawerStyle.style1,
      mainScreen: MainScreen(),
      menuScreen: MenuPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:dashboard/menu_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:authentication/authentication.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: const Text('Main page'),
        leading: const MenuWidget(),
      ),
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: _signOut,
        child: const Text('Logout'),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _signOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const Authentication()),
            (route) => false);
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MenuPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
  );
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_zoom_drawer/flutter_zoom_drawer.dart';

class MenuWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
      onPressed: () => ZoomDrawer.of(context)!.toggle(),
    );
  }
}
```

I've been searching for a solution but I couldn't find it. If you know how to solve this problem, please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
    ZoomDrawer(
      controller: z,
      borderRadius: 24,
      style: DrawerStyle.defaultStyle,
      openCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      slideWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      menuBackgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
      mainScreen: MainScreen(),
      menuScreen: MenuPage(),
    )
```

https://github.com/medyas/flutter_zoom_drawer/issues/105